# OpenCV and convexityDefects

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

So i am really new to `openCV` and all the image recognition stuff. So i use monodevelop and i installed OpenCV using `apt-get`and i included these files

`include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
include<iostream>
include<vector>
include<algorithm>
include <X11/Xlib.h>
include <X11/Xutil.h>`

but this `function` `convexityDefects()` shows as `undefined`

**EDIT**

So the problem is that the compiler shows that function `convexityDefects` is not defined in this scope

Here is the full code that i cant get to work -> [Code](https://github.com/jujojujo2003/OpenCVHandGuesture/blob/master/main.cpp)

Could you please point me out!?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). A few include statements simply isn't enough to reproduce, let alone fix, your problem. And what do you mean "shows as `undefined`"? What is the error that you get?

Comment: Actually the problem i think is in includes, beacose the when i try to compile it shows me that function is undefined in this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer i was looking for.....
The libraries i used to compile my project where in wrong location.

so i used `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` to find exactly where are my libs....

After that i included these libraries in `Code-Blocks` and everything magicly started to work.